# Not able to extract desired attribute value from a tag using XPath

Tags: java, xpath, xhtml

I have an XHTML like below:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="sample" content="Just for sample"/>
    <title/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sample Heading</h1>
    <p align="left">XHTML and HTML are relatives.<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to extract the attribute value of `align` from `<p>` using XPath expression in Java. So, I tried using this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);


DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("TestFile.xhtml");

//Create XPath

XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath Inst= xpathfactory.newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)Inst.evaluate("//p/@align",doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) 
   {
            Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(e);
    }
```

in Java code. But I am not getting any output. Even if I only write `//body`, nothing is getting extracted. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Any edit in the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element named `p` in your XHTML, even though it may appear so.

When you use the `xmlns` attribute in XML, you are declaring that the element bearing that attribute, and all descendant elements, are in that namespace (unless overridden explicitly with other namespace declarations).

So, the root element isn’t named `html`, it’s actually ‘html in the "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" namespace.’  The `html` part is called the “local part.”  The local name and the namespace URI are collectively known as a [QName](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#QName).

By convention, this is written by putting the namespace URI in braces as a prefix, so for the sake of discussion, the root element is `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html`, and the element you are seeking is `{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}p`.

One way to handle this is to [install a NamespaceContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext(javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext)), but for reasons which continue to elude me, Java SE has no public standard implementation of NamespaceContext, which makes setting it a chore.

An easier approach is to tailor your XPath expression to search for elements based on only the local part of each element:

```
Inst.evaluate("//*[local-name()='p']/@align", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

If you’re using [DocumentBuilderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html), remember to call [setNamespaceAware(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)) on it before creating a DocumentBuilder.

Comment: In fact I have used `DocumentBuilderFactory` and set `setNamepaceAware(true)`. I have edited my question to give more code snippet. So, you mean even if you set `setNamespaceAware` as true, I still need to add `[local-name()='p']`?

Comment: Yes.  `p` alone will look for an element with a local part of "p" and an empty namespace URI.

Comment: Ok, so that gives the answer to my main question. Thanks! I will mark the answer as accepted.